# How to do a custom binding with ReactFX's Var?

Tags: java, javafx, reactfx

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494930/do-properties-of-properties-make-sense) I was shown how to deal with the problem of having a property change by changing it's wrapping object and thus not sending updates that it changed. A solution was using ReactFX:

```
class Cell {

    private final ObjectProperty<Shape> shape = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Shape());
    // all getters and setterts

    public static class Shape {

        private final IntegerProperty size = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        // all getters and setterts
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Var<Number> sizeVar = Val.selectVar(cell.shapeProperty(), Shape::sizeProperty);
        sizeVar.addListener(
            (obs, oldSize, newSize) -> System.out.println("Size changed from "+oldSize+" to "+newSize));
}
```

So now if the `shape` property itself changes it triggers a change in `size` too (unless the new shape has the same size). But now I want to bind to the property with custom bindings and I have an problem explained below.

My data classes are these:

```
class Cell {

    private final ObjectProperty<Shape> shape = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    public final ObjectProperty<Shape> shapeProperty() { return shape; }
    public final Shape getShape()                      { return shapeProperty().get(); }
    public final void setShape(Shape shape)            { shapeProperty().set(shape); }

    // other properties
}

class Shape {

    private final IntegerProperty size = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public final IntegerProperty sizeProperty() { return size; }
    public final int getSize()                  { return size.get(); }
    public final void setSize(int size)         { sizeProperty().set(size); }

    // other properties
}
```

And i want to create a GUI representation for them by binding their properties to GUI properties. I do it this way:

```
class CellRepresentation extends Group {

    private final Cell cell;

    CellRepresentation(Cell cell) {

        this.cell = cell;
        getChildren().add(new ShapeRepresentation() /*, other representations of things in the cell*/);
    }

    private class ShapeRepresentation extends Cylinder {

        ObjectProperty<Shape> shape;

        private ShapeRepresentation() {

            super(100, 100);

            shape = new SimpleObjectProperty<Shape>(cell.getShape());
            shape.bind(cell.shapeProperty());

            Var<Number> sizeVar = Val.selectVar(cell.shapeProperty(), Shape::sizeProperty);

            // THIS WILL WORK
            materialProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
                if (shape.get() == null)
                    return new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                return new PhongMaterial(Color.RED);
            }, sizeVar));

            // THIS WILL NOT WORK
            materialProperty().bind(sizeVar.map(n -> {
                if (shape.get() == null)
                    return new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                return new PhongMaterial(Color.RED);
            }));
        }
    }

    // the other representations of things in the cell
}
```

When I run the code below the first option for binding will create a transparent cylinder. The second option will create a white (default color) cylinder. I don't know why this happens.

```
public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Cell cell = new Cell();
        CellRepresentation cellRep = new CellRepresentation(cell);

        Group group = new Group(cellRep);
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 200, 200, Color.AQUA);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I am also open to design suggestions if this is not a good way to create representations for the data classes using bindings.

Comment: What is `size` in your last code block? Don't you really need something like `if (sizeVar.getValue().intValue() == 1) { ...}` etc?

Comment: @James_D `size` is the property of `Shape`. I did try before with the line you wrote (taking the value from `sizeVar`) but there was no difference. I'll create an MCVE. i thought was just wrong usage.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused. Surely `size` is a member of `Shape`, but the binding is outside the `Shape` class. And that wouldn't compile anyway, because `size` is an `IntegerProperty` and cannot be compared to `1` by `==`. If that version is not working, the binding is probably getting garbage collected. Does my answer not work?

Comment: @James_D it's a no-MCVE confusion which i will solve. your solution doesn't work in my case and actually produces "worse" results than the one i posted so at least on some level they are not identical. hang on please...

Comment: @James_D ok, it was a bit of a convoluted problem in my code but I fixed it. So now i cheated and asked a slightly different question based on your answer but still same topic. I hope no one will mind...

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit annoying when you change a question which is answered, because then the answer has to be changed. See update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Val` and `Var` are "observable monadics" (think observable `Optional`s). They are either empty or hold a value. The `map` method works just like `Optional.map`: if the `Val` is empty, `map` results in an empty `Val`; otherwise it results in a `Val` containing the result of applying the function to the original `Val`'s value. So if `sizeVar` evaluates to `null`, the mapping results in an empty `Val` (so your material is set to `null`) without even evaluating your lambda expression.

To handle `null` (i.e. empty `Val`s), you should use `orElse` or similar methods:

```
private class ShapeRepresentation extends Cylinder {

    Val<Shape> shape;

    private ShapeRepresentation() {

        super(100, 100);

        shape = Val.wrap(cell.shapeProperty());

        Var<Number> sizeVar = shape.selectVar(Shape::sizeProperty);

        // THIS WILL WORK

        materialProperty().bind(shape
            .map(s -> new PhongMaterial(Color.RED))
            .orElseConst(new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT)));

        // SO WILL THIS

        materialProperty().bind(sizeVar
                .map(n -> {
                    if (n.intValue() == 1) return new PhongMaterial(Color.RED) ;
                    if (n.intValue() == 2) return new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE) ;
                    return new PhongMaterial(Color.WHITE);
                })
                .orElseConst(new PhongMaterial(Color.TRANSPARENT)));

    }
}
```

Updated example for testing:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Cell cell = new Cell();

        CellRepresentation cellRep = new CellRepresentation(cell);

        Group group = new Group(cellRep);

        ComboBox<Integer> sizeCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        sizeCombo.getItems().addAll(0, 1, 2);

        Shape shape = new Shape();
        shape.sizeProperty().bind(sizeCombo.valueProperty());


        CheckBox showShape = new CheckBox("Show shape");
        cell.shapeProperty().bind(Bindings.when(showShape.selectedProperty()).then(shape).otherwise((Shape)null));

        HBox controls = new HBox(5, showShape, sizeCombo);
        controls.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(group, controls, null, null, null);
        root.setBackground(null);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.AQUA);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `sizeVar` used here?

Comment: @Mark it's not, but the bindings you posted didn't rely on it either (they just needed to know if the shape was null/empty). I assumed you still needed it somewhere else in your code.

Comment: sorry, i thought that using the `sizeVar` inside the binding will work but it doesn't. I tired `s -> { if(sizeVar.getValue().intValue() == 1) return new PhongMaterial(Color.RED); else return new PhongMaterial(Color.BLUE);` i need to tell the binding to listen to `sizeVar`.

Comment: @Mark What is the actual logic you are trying to implement? (Including the case where the shape and/or size are null.)

Comment: If the shape or size are null then no shape is displayed in the cell. i do it by making it transparent. if not then the color varies by the size the algorithm doesn't matter. something like: for size == 1 red, for size ==2 blue... otherwise white.

Comment: @Mark Well the same thing works just fine for me. See update.

Comment: Yes. it's because when shape is null then size is also null. what i'm trying to say (very badly until now) is that the solution with `map` allows me to listen to changes only in that variable. The custom `createXxxBinding` allowed me to specify a list of observables as the 2nd argument. The map allows me only 1 as I see it. so how do i listen to multiple variables this way?